# C# - Constant value '4294901760' cannot be converted to a 'int'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Greetings,

I can't believe I'm asking such a basic question, but it doesn't make sense so here it is :).

In C# on Windows Phone 7 / .net, I'm trying to define a constant in a class as follows:

```
// error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. 
// An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
public const int RED = 0xffff0000;
```

If I put an (int) cast around it like so, I get another error:

```
// error CS0221: Constant value '4294901760' cannot be converted to a 'int' 
// (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)        
public const int RED = (int)0xffff0000;
```

But I know that my int is 32-bit, hence has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=vs.80).aspx

So what gives?

Thanks in advance!

swine

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you note, the range of `Int32` is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, so any number within that range can be held, but ONLY numbers within that range can be held. 4,294,901,760 is greater than 2,147,483,647, so doesn't fit in an `Int32`.

What to do about this depends on what you want to achieve. If you just want an `Int32` with the bit pattern `ffff0000`, then as suggested use `unchecked` :

```
int y = unchecked((int)0xffff0000);
```

`y` now has the value -65536, which is that bit pattern interpreted as a signed integer.

However! If you actually want the value 4,294,901,760 you should use a datatype appropriate to it - so `UInt32`.

Comment: Yes of course. Must be late! So... if I use unchecked, will c# truncate the value or wrap it around, preserving the data?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. So: In an unchecked context, if an expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type, the result is truncated.

Comment: @Vik that page is a bit misleading (the latest version is better) - since the datatypes here are the same size, it's not really 'truncated'

Comment: You are right AakashM, value will start over: from minValue + overflow size.

Comment: Thanks AakashM! The confusion was stemming from c#'s way of handling int32 vs uint32... That clears it up!

Comment: ...another reason for me to be annoyed by c# (if I had a dollar for every reason c# annoyed me, the stacked dollars would be the height of a mountain)... literals defined by 0x are well understood whether they are signed or unsigned...

Answer (score 4):

`int` is a signed integer ranging from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
What you want is an unsigned integer, i.e. `uint`, just like the first error message tells you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using unchecked as suggested by the compiler message:

```
public const int RED = unchecked((int)0xffff0000);
```

This defines `RED` as -65536, which is 0xffff0000 interpreted as signed int.

Answer (score 2):

```
public const uint RED = 0xffff0000;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you around the unchecked:

```
public const int RED = 0xffff << 16;
```