# Constant value cannot be converted to int

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I can't see why line#5 fails to compile whereas line#4 is ok.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte b = 0;
    int i = (int)(0xffffff00 | b);       // ok
    int j = (int)(0xffffff00 | (byte)0); // error: Constant value cannot be converted to a 'int' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Constant value '4294901760' cannot be converted to a 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027572/c-sharp-constant-value-4294901760-cannot-be-converted-to-a-int)

Comment: @ColinCochrane It's related, but not a dup.  That explains why the value cannot be cast to an int, but this question is about why the error only occurs for a constant and not for a variable that was set to the same value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile-time constants are checked differently to other code, basically.

A cast of a compile-time constant into a type whose range doesn't include that value will always fail unless you *explicitly* have an `unchecked` expression. The cast is evaluated at compile time.

However, the cast of an expression which is classified as a *value* (rather than a constant) is evaluated at execution time, and handles overflow either with an exception (in checked code) or by truncating bits (in unchecked code).

You can see this slightly more easily using `byte` and just a `const` field vs a `static readonly` field:

```
class Test
{
    static readonly int NotConstant = 256;
    const int Constant = 256;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte okay = (byte) NotConstant;
        byte fail = (byte) Constant;  // Error; needs unchecked
    }
}
```